# Not able to get the javascript ".length" output into a variable

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am using d3.js to load a csv file using d3.csv and store it in 'List'. When I assign the List.length value to a variable (totalElems), the value always comes to 0. However, the List.length does return the actual size of the array. Where am I going wrong ?
N.B: 
I am using chrome console for this exercise with python HTTP server
Attached along-with is a screenshot of the error.
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Post *code*, not a *picture* of code. Pictures are hard to read, and can't be properly indexed by the site (yet; I'm sure they could with enough effort).

Comment: is the variable in the same scope you are trying to access it in?

Comment: [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) is *asynchronous*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I solved it by converting the files to .json (using a perl script on the fly) and including the same in my script tag programatically.